# Reset UITableViewCell checkmarks For Button Action

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

The following code starts with a blank cell and add a checkmark when I select the cell but, I want to remove all checkmarks while I am tapping button externally. Can you please suggest me how can I implement this?

```
  - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

    if (indexPath.section == 0) {

    switch (indexPath.row) {
        case 0:
            labelInfo.text=@"1";
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark; 
            break;
        case 1:
            labelInfo.text=@"2";
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark; 
            break;
        case 2:
            labelInfo.text=@"3";
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark; 
            break;
        case 3:
            labelInfo.text=@"4";
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark; 
            break;
        case 4:
            labelInfo.text=@"5";
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark; 
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use a model, for example properties `text` and `selected`. In `cellForRowAtIndexPath` set the label text and accessory view accordingly. To change something do it in the **model** and reload the row or the table view.

Answer (score 1):

In button's `IBAction` reload the table and in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` write `cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;`.

Answer (score 0):

if you are new the easiest solution would be to manage NSMutableArray for selected index.

```
NSMutableArray * selectedArray = [NSMutableArray new];
```

On every Did select Check if selected indexpath is already present in your array?

```
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

if([selectedArray containsObject:indexPath]){
//Your cell is already selected then unselect it
 [selectedArray removeObject:indexPath];

}
else{
//Add object to indexpath
  [selectedArray addObject:indexPath];
}

[tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];

}
```

This is your cellForRowAtIndexPath will be

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

        UITableViewCell* cell = [tableView  dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"YOUR_ID" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        [cell setAccessoryType: UITableViewCellAccessoryNone];
        if ([selectedArray containsObject:indexPath]){
             [cell setAccessoryType: UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];
        }
        return  cell;

    }
```

When You want to clear all check mark remove all item from array and reload cell or

```
[YOUR_TABLEVIEW reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[tableView indexPathsForVisibleRows] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code., Just update the previous clicked index row by using a flag value. hope it may helps.

```
@interface ViewController ()
{
    int previousClickedIndex; //To save previous clicked row
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    previousClickedIndex = -1; //Initialize with a negative value
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

    if (indexPath.section == 0) {

        if(previousClickedIndex>-1)
        {

            UITableViewCell *prevousSelectedCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:previousClickedIndex inSection:indexPath.section]];
            prevousSelectedCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

        }

        switch (indexPath.row) {
            case 0:
            //labelInfo.text=@"1";
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
            break;
            case 1:
            //labelInfo.text=@"2";
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
            break;
            case 2:
            //labelInfo.text=@"3";
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
            break;
            case 3:
            //labelInfo.text=@"4";
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
            break;
            case 4:
            //labelInfo.text=@"5";
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
            break;
            default:
            break;
        }

        previousClickedIndex = indexPath.row;
    }
}
```